# new Date в цикле повторяется значение

Tags: javascript, localstorage

```
 showFinalScore: function (score, names) {
    var final = "<p>FINAL SCORE: ";
    for (var i in score) {
        if (score.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            var key = Date.now();
            var obj = {'name': names[i], 'points':score[i]};
            localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
        }
    }
    final += "</p>";
    this.element.innerHTML += final;
  }
```

Функция динамически создает localStorage. Ключ каждый раз создается при помощи даты. Но иногда проскальзывает одинаковая дата, и ключ перезатирается.
Как это можно исправить???
Я надеюсь я доходчиво написал )
new Date().getTime() я тоже пробовал))

Comment: name в ключ добавить нельзя? Вы можете перед циклом взять date.now, а внутри просто его инкрементить, для надежности

Comment: Или сгенерированное [случайное число](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) приписывать к ключу?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_now.asp

Comment: интересуюсь, как предполагается в дальнейшем читать это из `localStorage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно делать проверку на наличие такого ключа в хранилище и переопределять на новый, если текущий занят.

```
while (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    key = Date.now();
}
```

Comment: тогда уж `while`

Comment: Не будет ли страница при таком цикле виснуть? Асинхронно с микро паузой думаю было бы лучше. Правда сомнительно для такой простой функциональности писать через асинхронный код.

Answer (score 1):

Можно инкрементировать в конец даты счётчик:

```
var keyStart = ""+Date.now();
var key = keyStart;
for(var i=1;;i++) {
    if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         key = keyStart +"["+i+"]";
    }
    else {
         localStorage.setItem(key,value);
         break;
    }
}
```